# 4ormat how and where to edit the page html code?

Tags: html, web-services, liquid

I have a pro yearly plan with 4ormat.

I want to add custom fields to the contact form as well as edit the html of other pages? Is it possible?

I searched a lot for their documentation but found very few results and they weren't much help.

I found their contents page html code and added the line

```
    {% if page.id == '234242' %}
    <h2>This Is Contact Us Page</h2>
    {% endif %}
```

But nothing happened.., Even if something had happened.. i would have still needed to edit the content/html of the contacts page.

Is there any way to edit html code of 4ormat pages? Or do they have any developer tutorials?

Any/all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in fact possible to edit the HTML for Content Pages on 4ormat - custom fields for the contact form aren't supported at this time.  Please email info@4ormat.com, and we can give you a "Simple Page" into which you could embed an external form from a site like WuFoo.com.

Thanks,
Stefan Pintaric | Customer Support Lead 
4ormat.com